# Excel Budget Spreadsheet Microsoft Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I have used a Microsoft Word 2007 annual budget spreadsheet template for budgets since they were .xlr. Npw they are .xlsx files and when I am working in them they take forever to process each entry and there is a comment on the file name line that says (not responding). I noticed that the .xlr files were 20kish in size and these new ones are in the 200k size. I have installed all of the updates I can find (Microsoft said they were already downloaded when I tried) and I am clueless about the cause or how to fix it. Can you give me some insight?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Excel never had an .xlr file type. That is a format used by Works, a much earlier software.

If the file has become corrupted, you could try copying and pasting just the formulas into a new file: Copy all cells in the sheet wit Ctrl-A, open a new workbook and use Paste Special > Formulas.

That will copy formulas and constants, like text labels. After that, check the formulas and ensure they don't refer to anything outside the new workbook. Formulas referencing external files can slow things down.

In a second Paste Special you could paste the formats, but sometimes excessive formatting is the reason for spreadsheet slowness, so you may want to apply formats manually.